# How to prove that this is the taylor series?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series

So I was thinking of calculating $\int f'(x)dx$ using integration by parts. I was guessing this would give us the Taylor series. Anyways, we get $$\int f'(x)dx=xf'(x)-\int xf''(x)dx=xf'(x)-\frac{x^2}{2}f''(x)+\int\frac{x^2}{2}f'''(x)dx=\int \frac{x^N}{N!}f^{(N+1)}(x)dx \pm\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{k+1}x^kf^{(k)}(x)}{k!}$$ Where we have plus if $N$ is odd and a minus if it's even. Note that $f(x)$ must be differentiable by $N$ times. You can use u-substitution to change $x$ into $x-a$ to get:$$f(x)=\int \frac{(x-a)^N}{N!}f^{(N+1)}(x-a)dx \pm\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(x-a)^kf^{(k)}(x-a)}{k!}$$ So how do I turn this into the Taylor Series?

Comment: I would compute $\int_{a}^x f'(t)\,dt$ rather than an indefinite integral. All those constants you are stuck dealing with.

Comment: @ThomasAndrew Where $f'(a)=0$? Why is the definite one better? Just want to learn more :)

Comment: How do you know $f$ is differentiable $n$ times for $n > 1$?

Comment: @politeproofs I will add that

Comment: It's an implied assumption when talking about Taylor series theorems. @politeproofs

Comment: @ThomasAndrews But OP said he was thinking about calculating $\int f'$ using integration by parts, which is not really that?

Comment: @politeproofs I wanted to change the series into taylor series

Comment: The right side you are seeing is the Taylor series of $f(a)-f(a+(-x)),$ when $a=x.$ That seems like a very small case of a Taylor series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You can just use u-sub to generalize it. I edited the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Thomas Andrews suggested, this all works out nicer if you are looking at $\int_a^x f'(t) dt=f(x)-f(a)$. Then if you're just working fast and loose, you get

$$\int_a^x f'(t) dt = x f'(x) - a f'(a) - \int_a^x t f''(t) dt.$$

This doesn't exactly achieve what you want to achieve, because you really want the leading term here to be $f'(a)(x-a)$. The trick is to choose your antiderivative of $1$ "just right", specifically you choose it to vanish at the right endpoint, i.e. $t-x$, so that there is no term with $f'(x)$ involved. So you write

$$\int_a^x f'(t) dt = -(a-x) f'(a) - \int_a^x (t-x) f''(t) dt=(x-a) f'(a) + \int_a^x (x-t) f''(t) dt$$

and this iterates nicely to give the Taylor series. You can find this sort of writeup in derivations of Taylor's theorem with the integral remainder.